# Upload image from facebook app

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to upload image from a Facebook app. I get the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data thrown in /storage/content/00/103300/gjutveckling.se/public_html/fb/src/base_facebook.php on line 886

This is my code. The strange thing is that i got it to work, but then all if the sudden it stopped working. Can this be a SSL related problem, I just got a new one? Any suggestions must appreciated!

```
<?php   



$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                       'appId'  => $appid,
                       'secret' => $appsecret,
                      'fileUpload' => true, 
                       'cookie' => true,));

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);  

$FILE_PATH = 'imdage_' . $user_id . '.jpg';

$args = array('message' => 'message');

$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);

$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);



?>
```

I tried this aswell, it doesn't give me an error, but no photo is uploaded.

```
 <?php


function upload_to_facebook($image_data, $access_token)
    {
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'xxx',
'secret' => 'xxx',
));

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'get', array('access_token' => $access_token));
foreach ($albums[data] as $album)
{
if ($album['name'] == $image_data['album_name'])
{
$album_id = $album['id'];
}
}

if (!$album_id)
{ 
//Create an album
$album_details = array(
'message'    => 'Album by FB APP',
'access_token'   => $access_token,
'name'   => $image_data['album_name']
);
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);
//Get album ID of the album you’ve just created
$album_id = $create_album['id'];
}

//Upload a photo to album of ID…
$photo_details = array(
'message'    => 'test image',
'access_token'   => $access_token,
);

$photo_details['skrivreglerny.png'] = '@' . realpath($image_data['file']);

$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);

return $upload_photo;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
$photo_details = array(
        'message'        => 'message',
        'access_token'   => 'USER ACCESS TOKEN',
    );

    $photo_details['image'] = '@'.realpath($image_data['file']);
    $upload_photo = $facebook->api(('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

see this link
http://pramodsivadas.co.in/2011/11/upload-an-image-to-a-facebook-album-facebook-php-sdk/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry for slow response. I tried the code on your site. Unfortunately I get the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' in /storage/content/00/103300/gjutveckling.se/public_html/fb/dela/index.php on line 110 

Have you tried the code yourself?

Comment: I think the issue may be with single quotes. While copying from the website single quotes are replaced with some other characters. Tty replacing all single quotes with the correct one.

Comment: Thank's for staying with me on this. The error disappeared when I repleced all the strange charachters with single quotes, but no image is uploaded. I will post my code below so you can see it. Edit: I wasn't aloud to answer my own question, so I will paste it in my orgiginal question.